# Call a script when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have a script that helps to annotate an image. i Just want to run this script only when i click the button. I've tried to use the event onclick for the button but it is not working. 
Here is the code

```
<head>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/jquery-ui.css">

    ////////////// those are the scripts that i use in the function //////
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlight.js/zenburn.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/css/theme-dark/annotorious-dark.css" />
    <script src="highlight.js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/annotorious.min.js"></script>
    /////////////
    <script>
    $("#annotation").click(function() {
        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
        //function of annotation
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="submit" id="annotation" >
    <img src="stylo.png"  style="width: 30px ; height:50px" alt="Submit">
</button>
</body>
```

But this is not working , i still have the script running when i load the page. I just need to call it when the button " annotation" is clicked.

Comment: _"But this is not working"_  ? What is that ? Any error in `console` ?

Comment: Do you have an error in the console ?

Comment: no there is no errors. like i said , i just want to run the script only when button is clicked. But with the try that i made , it is not working because the script runs just after i load the page, without clicking the button.

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Does the page get refreshed?

Comment: @yassine, Is `submit button` wrapped in `form` ?

Comment: Thats what I was suspecting as well...@Rayon ..anything to do with the script being outside `$(document).ready()` ???

Comment: @Rayon it  is just a button that calls a script. Nothing so complicated but i can't find the answer.

Comment: @SamGhatak, I don't think so.. As `script` is last child of the `body`.. Is button getting appended dynamically ? Can we have a fiddle to play with ?

Comment: it is from [ http://annotorious.github.io ]. i just added a button that runs the script

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#annotation").click( function()
           {
            alert("Hello!");
            // hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); //function of annotation
           });
    });
    </script>

    <button type="submit" id="annotation" > <img src="stylo.png"  style="width: 30px ; height:50px" alt="Submit"></button>
```

I dont know about your hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); function but as far as the function execution on button click, you have to write that code in $(document).ready() function. It works well as i already tested with an alert();

---

---------------------------**UPDATED**--------------------------------

I have tested it by using cdn of jquery and highlightjs

```
<head>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.9.1/highlight.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#annotation").click( function()
           {
              hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); //function of annotation
           });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="submit" id="annotation" > 
      <img src="stylo.png"  style="width: 30px ; height:50px" alt="Submit">
    </button>
  </body>
```

Comment: i also tested it with the alert , it works. like i said earlier the button works fine with the alert but when i want to call the script it doesn't work

Comment: Yassine i actually don't understand that hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); thing.. It would be more clear if you could give that function definition or the library from which that function is to be called

Comment: I searched about that function just now... Here is what i found.  `hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
hljs.initHighlighting();`